# When using '@pinia-plugin-persistedstate/nuxt', can I save keys and values by custom?

Tags: vuejs3, nuxt3

I am not good at English. Please understand.
Pinia plug-in '@pinia-plugin-persistedstate/nuxt' to store and manage data on sessionStorage on nuxt3
I'm using it.
Persistedstate only provides one key to one store.
Is it possible to save keys and values by custom?

```
Browser Storage Status
[key]              [value]
user               {"token":"QpwL5tke4Pnpja7X4","userAddress":null}        

Browser Storage Status I want
[key]              [value]
token            QpwL5tke4Pnpja7X4 
userAddress       null
```

From the userStore
When the user logs in, save the token
The user saves the address to userAddress.

// store/user.ts

```
import { defineStore } from 'pinia';
import { ref } from 'vue';

export const useUserStore = defineStore('user', () => {

  //auth
  const token = ref(null)
  const getToken = computed(() => token.value);
  const getAddress = computed(() => userAddress.value);
  const setToken = (data: any) => {
    console.log('settoken', data);
    token.value = data;
  };
  const removeToken = () => {
    token.value = null;
  };

//address
  const userAddress = ref(null)
  const setAddress = (params: any) => {
    userAddress.value = params;
  };

  return {
    token,
    userAddress,
    getToken,
    getAddress,
    setToken,
    removeToken,
    setAddress,
  };
}, {
  persist: {
    storage: persistedState.sessionStorage,
  },
});
```